# Diff after committing locally

Tags: mercurial, diff, commit

I just cloned a repo from their remote.

I built the software, changed about 4 files, **committed** them locally and now want to create a patch that I can show them.

When I run :

```
hg diff -U8p abc efg pqr > patch_file
```

I don't see the changes I made. Does `hg diff` only compare the current files with the last committed files?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Why do not use bundles, if both sides are Mercurial, instead of diff?

Comment: @LazyBadger: I didn't know of that. yes, I could. Their website mentioned this approach however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To `diff` the working directory against a particular revision `REV`, use

   ```
   hg diff -r REV
   ```
2. To compare two revisions against each other, use

   ```
   hg diff -r REV1 -r REV2
   ```
3. To figure out which revisions to compare, examine the output of `hg log`. If you'll be doing this a lot and the base revision is fixed, give it a name (e.g., *whatipulled*) with

   ```
   hg tag -r REV whatipulled
   ```

   You can then specify `whatipulled` as the revision, instead of a numeric rev id (or a hash).
4. To export your diffs in a richer format, including commit comments etc., you can also use the following which is designed for this purpose:

   ```
   hg export -r REV
   ```
5. There's also `hg bundle -r REV`, which produces a binary file with similar information.
6. But if you're sending changes back to the parent repo, the best method is to use `hg push`. It communicates your changesets directly to the parent; you don't even need to know which changesets need pushing. Of course, you must have the right to push to the parent repo.

   ```
   hg push [ parent_repo_url ]
   ```

   (If you pulled from it, mercurial should already know the path and you can leave it out).
7. If the parent repo is on bitbucket and you don't have pu, you can set up your own account on bitbucket, pull/push to that from your local repo, and then issue a "pull request" to the project repo, asking them to pull from you.

All of the above have options to control their behavior, which see.

Answer (score 2):

From `hg help diff`

> If only one revision is specified then that revision is compared to the working directory

In your diff for -r you must to use old tip (latest "not your" changeset) and update to tip (your latest changeset) before diffing.

If some binary data was modified in your changesets, don't forget to use -g option

`hg up & hg diff -r <CSET> -g > some.patch`

Improved diff for any active changeset and without hand-work for detecting base changeset (for linear history == in single branch)

`hg diff -r "parent(min(outgoing()))" -r tip`

Answer (score 1):

By default, `hg diff` compares the currently checked out file with the last commit. You can change this by adding options:

- `-r REV` compares the currently checked out files with a specific revision `REV`.
- `-c REV` shows the changes made by revision `REV`

So in your case `hg diff -c 123 ...` would give you the diff for commit 123.

Comment: What if I needed to `diff` it against the initially cloned repo. The one before I made any changes at all. What would `REV` for that version?

Comment: While this may not be exactly what user asked, this was incredibly helpful to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `hg outgoing` is exactly what you want -- it compares what you've committed locally with what is at the default remote server and shows you a list of those changesets or with `-p` the commits.

That does, however, shows each changeset separately.  If you want to see all the changes combined, you'd have to do `hg diff -r HERE -r THERE` or since `-r HERE` is a default, `hg diff -r THERE`

I see you've asked in a comment "How do I know what THERE is", where *THERE* is the last changeset remote has, and you can get that answer by doing `hg outgoing`.  If `hg outgoing` shows it would send changesets 66, 67, and 68, then you want to do `hg diff -r 65` to compare what's already there (65) with what's local (68).

Comment: Using revset (directly in diff) will be smarter. In case of linear history revset will be "parent(min(outgoing()))"

Comment: Good call.  You should change your answer to that.