# Mercurial prevent deleting of file silently on merge

Tags: version-control, mercurial

So I have an easily reproducable issue. I have a branch (let's call it branch1) where I added some files. From this branch I create 2 other branches (branch2 and branch3). In one of these I remove one/more files I added in the original branch (let's say I remove example.txt in branch3).

Now when I merge branch 2 with branch3 locally, mercurial will silently delete example.txt, however I don't like that this is done silently without my knowledge. I want mercurial to explicitly ask me this, without me having to manually go over all these files in branch2 and adding a meaningless \n or something to prevent the silent delete.

Does anybody know if there is a commandline argument to give to merge to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: If you know the name of the file that goes missing, just extract it again into your working tree before committing...?

Comment: Well in this very simple example it is very easy to see, but if you're merging with another branch with high amount of commits it is of course a lot harder to debug which files exactly go missing all of a sudden, especially when you're not informed during merge.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "if". Consider diffing your working tree against its primary parent, to find out which files are deleted in this particular comparison. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15051591/1256452

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know if there is a commandline argument to give to merge to achieve this behaviour?

Yes. Write own mergetool with "expected" by you (but unusual) behavior and use it with `-t` command-line option for merge command